# distribute tokens to whitelisted users

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

How would a simple function, which when called, automatically distributes tokens to all whitelisted users of a mapping look like?

Comment: Here's a hint: You can't loop over values of a mapping. You will need an array of whitelisted users.

Comment: cheers, kept trying what u said I couldn't :)

Comment: I made it easy for you:
https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender/#/
but you are right - you can't loop over mapping